# Is there any change in the way screen capture/ snapshot is to be restricted in Android 9.0(Pie)?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

In the onCreate() method of the activity, the below snippet is used-

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't received an update yet on device to test the functionality. While I was trying to check the functionality at SauceLabs(online test farm) for the activities where the above snippet was used, **the screen went blank**(Devices:Pixel and Pixel2 v9.0). 
This isn't the case for earlier versions(tested till v8.1.0). It works fine in earlier versions and taking screenshot is restricted.

In the android development documentation, the following is mentioned:

**int   FLAG_SECURE Window flag: treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams

Wanted to check if anyone tested this scenario and faced any issue. Or it is just that the latest OS version considers online test lab screens insecure.
Target API : 26

Comment: My guess is that `FLAG_SECURE` got upgraded to block whatever Sauce Labs uses. This is one of those things that you really need to test with actual hardware, IMHO. I have used `FLAG_SECURE` on Android 9.0 devices without other issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for the suggestion, and the confirmation using actual hardware. Shall update once we procure the device.